# What actually constitutes a 'rip' in the fabric of spacetime?

Tags: spacetime, singularities, wormholes

Science fiction writers often use the term 'rip' in the fabric of spacetime to provide a means of either time travel or instantaneous travel from one corner of the universe to another. But I've also read and heard bonafide physicists use this term as well, so I suspect there is some credence to its meaning in standard physics principles and the mathematics that model them.

I understand that gravity is just the curvature of space time and that immense gravitational fields such as those near a black hole can cause extreme *warping* , but at what point do we consider spacetime *ripping*? Is this the point at which some singularity occurs in the field equations? And if so what's happening physically?

Comment: Apart from possibly [the big rip](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_Rip) I've never heard a physicist talk about spacetime being ripped. It is not a term that exists outside SF.

Comment: @JohnRennie  Richard Gott, Max Tegmark, Michio Kaku, Brian Greene just to name of few. Of course all popularized, layman physics, and the meaning never explained in gory detail.

Comment: Can you give us a link so we can see exactly what they said. My guess is that they used the term in a pop sci way and it is effectively meaningless.

Comment: In his postdoc days Briane Green did some work on topology changes in string theory. That might count as a technical definition of a rip. However GR has no mechanism for topology change. The manifold topology is an input not a prediction.

Comment: @JohnRennie Bryce DeWitt here: https://www.washingtonpost.com/archive/opinions/1985/03/03/gravity-is-the-force-that-makes-the-apple-fall-the-clue-to-creation/3e0f34f5-fb81-4785-bdd1-c06e5b0034a7/?utm_term=.74e934272655 was quoted:  "Tiny wormholes, tears and lumps may appear in a statistically fluctuating fabric of space-time at the minute level."

Comment: @JohnRennie here I'm interpreting 'tear' to mean the same as a 'rip'. Or maybe a rip is a large scale tear? Paul Davies has also used the term.

Comment: That's the [quantum foam idea](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_foam), but it really means that spacetime isn't well described as smooth manifold at very short distances. Spacetime isn't ripping or tearing in any useful sense since at that scale smooth spacetime doesn't exist.

Comment: We ought to [continue this in the chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71/the-h-bar) - the site is already nagging me about extended conversations in comments. It seems to me the problem is that we haven't agreed on what your question is asking let alone what the answer is. The chat is busiest in the late afternoon to evening UK time, say 18:00 to midnight UTC. If you want to ask there it should trigger a lively discussion.

Comment: @JohnRennie but even at the smallest scale what justifies that term? Is there an allusion the rip could be grown bigger, and if so where does that lead?

Comment: @JohnRennie ok. Thanks. I'm PST, so morning hours for me

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/46745/discussion-between-docscience-and-john-rennie).